# Distribution certificate with fingerprint hasn't been imported successfully

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

Before today, `eas build -profile production --platform ios` worked well. But since, it give me this error. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

```
Preparing credentials
Creating keychain
Preparing credentials for target 'XXXX'
Getting distribution certificate fingerprint and common name
Fingerprint = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", common name = XXXXXX
Writing distribution certificate to /var/folders/dz/XXXXXXX
Importing distribution certificate into the keychain
Initializing provisioning profile
Validating whether distribution certificate has been imported successfully
Destroying keychain - /var/folders/dz/XXXXXXX/T/turtle-v2-XXXXXXX
Distribution certificate with fingerprint XXXXXX hasn't been imported successfully
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this issue can be fixed by installing the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificate

Sauce: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1331, https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/

Answer (score 0):

The other answer explains what needs to be done, but not how.

To fix the error *"Error: Distribution certificate with fingerprint XYZ hasn't been imported successfully"* download the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations certificate from:

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer

Then install it to Keychain with:

```bash
security add-trusted-cert -d -r unspecified -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db ~/Downloads/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer
```

(I got the command from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67334871/4034572).)